# compare 2 xlsx files and highlight differences using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

can any one please provide me pointers on how to compare 2 xlsx files.
I am unable to paste the code here.I am new to Java.. and learning .
It would be great if any pointers are there...
Basically I ma looking to compare 2 XLSX file which ignores the case

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the POI examples - i.e. into the [ExcelComparator](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/ExcelComparator.java)

Comment: Thank you so much KIWIwings

Comment: The link doesn't exist. That's the correct one: https://github.com/jbolaky/multi-java-frameworks-tutorials/blob/master/apache-poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ExcelComparator.java

Comment: I've fixed the link - due to JPMS repacking the package name switched from ss/examples to examples/ss